# How to Add tags to newly created S3 buckets using boto3 from the scratch(which haven't tagged initially)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to add tags to s3 buckets, newly created ones, and the existing ones using python boto3.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


s3bucket=boto3.client("s3")
s3=boto3.resource('s3')
falcon_s3=False



print ("=================Adding tags to S3 Buckets==================")
list_bucket=s3bucket.list_buckets()


for buckets in list_bucket['Buckets']:

    try:
    
        Bucket_Existing_tags = s3.BucketTagging(buckets['Name']).tag_set
    
        for tags in Bucket_Existing_tags:
            if tags["Key"]=="Falcon Managed" and tags["Value"] =="true":
                print("This Bucket is belonged to Falcons -->"+ buckets["Name"])
                falcon_s3=True
                break
        else:
                bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(buckets['Name'])
                tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
                tags.append({'Key':'Technical:Patcher', 'Value': 'goats'})
                Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':tags})
                print('Tags added for ---> ' + buckets['Name'])


    except ClientError as e:
         print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

for that, I have created this script which is checking for buckets that have the tags already, and inside it check for falocon managed or not. if it's not it puts another tag set. when re-running the approach doesn't work because multiple times they don't allow to add same tags (but this should be possible since we do it with other resources). But this script is not working with s3 buckets which don't have tags initially (newly created ones)

so I need to add tags to all the buckets in that particular account(including the new ones which don't have tags) and if it is falcon managed it doesn't have to add any tags. but if it's not falcon managed, new tags must be added(without removing the existing tags). how do I modify this code for that purpose?

Outputs:

```
=================Adding tags to S3 Buckets==================

Unexpected error: An error occurred (NoSuchTagSet) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: The TagSet does not exist
Unexpected error: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same key
This Bucket is belonged to Falcons -->test-1-test-tag-adder
Tags added for ---> test-2-test-tag-adder
Unexpected error: An error occurred (NoSuchTagSet) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: The TagSet does not exist
Unexpected error: An error occurred (NoSuchTagSet) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: The TagSet does not exist
Unexpected error: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same key
Unexpected error: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by catching the thrown NoSuchTagSet error when there are no tags. The TagSet is then created with your default values.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3bucket = boto3.client("s3")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
falcon_s3 = False

print("=================Adding tags to S3 Buckets==================")
list_bucket = s3bucket.list_buckets()

for bucket in list_bucket:
    try:
        existing_bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(bucket).tag_set

        for tags in existing_bucket_tagging:
            if tags["Key"] == "Falcon Managed" and tags["Value"] == "true":
                print("This Bucket is belonged to Falcons -->" + bucket)
                falcon_s3 = True
                break

    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchTagSet':
            print(bucket + ",does not have tags, adding tag")

            bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(bucket)

            bucket_tagging.put(
                Tagging={
                    'TagSet': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'Technical:Patcher',
                            'Value': 'goats'
                        },
                    ]
                }
            )
            print('Tags added for ---> ' + bucket)
        else:
            print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```